# React-native-vision-camera can't access to normal camera in back

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, react-native

i am trying to use 'normal' camera on my iphone 11 pro.
I use react-native-vision-camera.
When i run this code:

```js
  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const deviceBack = devices.back;
  console.log(deviceBack?.devices)
```

I get only 2 cameras : `["ultra-wide-angle-camera", "wide-angle-camera"]`, I don't want a wide camera, I want to access to my normal camera, how to do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** - Single-lens smartphone cameras commonly have a wide-angle lens of roughly 22mm and 30mm equivalent. So basically, you would want to choose wide-angle, as this is the "normal" type.

---

based on the react-native documentation, there are three Identifiers for a physical camera (one that exists on the back/front of the device):

`"ultra-wide-angle-camera"` | `"wide-angle-camera"` | `"telephoto-camera"`

---

`"ultra-wide-angle-camera"`: A built-in camera with a shorter focal length than that of a wide-angle camera. (focal length between below 24mm)

`"wide-angle-camera"`: A built-in wide-angle camera. (focal length between 24mm and 35mm)

`"telephoto-camera"`: A built-in camera device with a longer focal length than a wide-angle camera. (focal length between above 85mm)

---

now that we have that settled, let's take a look at cameras' focal lengths that are equivalent to phone cameras' focal length ([resource](https://thesmartphonephotographer.com/smartphone-camera-focal-length/))

| Camera type | Focal length | Angle-of-view |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wide-angle | 22mm to 30mm | ~84° to ~62° |
| Telephoto | 50mm to 80mm | ~40° to ~25° |
| Ultrawide-angle | 12mm to 18mm | ~112° to ~90° |
| Periscope | 103mm to 125mm | ~20° to ~16° |

what is considered a "normal" focal length is 35mm,  so you should choose wide-angle since it is the closest (and eventually with the angle of view the user might be even closer to 35mm), further more the wide-angle is the most common focal-length for phone camera lens