# How to switch camera devices in React-native using vision-camera

Tags: react-native, camera, react-native-vision-camera

I'm using [react-native-vision-camera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera), this doc says there are multi lens such as `wide-angle-camera`, `telephoto-camera`, `ultra-wide-angle-camera`. I would like to switch camera lens on camera view. I tried to find some solutions on this doc, but not found yet to switch camera lens.
I can select the initial camera as Doc says `const devices = useCameraDevices('wide-angle-camera')`, but I'm not sure how to switch camera lens once it's mounted.

Comment: That would be such a cool feature. Did you figure it out (or create an Issue on the GitHub?) EDIT: I found your issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1273

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71287639/react-native-vision-camera-cant-access-to-normal-camera-in-back